# What can be done with JavaScript that can't be done with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning web development and i have 1 year or programming experience with PHP, should I start with JS or JQuery? is there anything that can be done only with JavaScript?

Comment: always learn javascript first. jquery is a javascript library, not a language.

Comment: ...What is it that makes people think jQuery is some magical thing outside of JS?

Comment: Since jQuery is a JavaScript library, theoretically you can do anything. If you are talking about the current API, string concatenation is something you cannot do with jQuery. jQuery's primary goal is to provide a wrapper for the clunky DOM API.

Comment: @cHao I think people hear how awesome it is and don't bother looking at what it actually is/does.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is just a javascript library.  So, jQuery is javascript - it is not another language.  JQuery is written in javascript itself.  You could not use jQuery without understanding javascript.

The very first thing you need to do is learn javascript.  Then, once you've learned the basics of the language, you can decide if the extra functionality that the jQuery library offers would be useful to the problems you're trying to solve.  So, you don't pick one or the other.  You start with javascript and all the functionality that offers and then you decide if you want to ADD to that the functionality that the jQuery library offers.

Personally, if I was doing cross browser web page scripting, I would absolutely use one of the popular javascript libraries such as jQuery or YUI because they both make web page scripting easier and make it easier to do things in a cross browser fashion (the libraries themselves handle a bunch of the browser differences for you).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a JavaScript library; you can't do anything in jQuery without JavaScript.  So, you should probably start learning JavaScript syntax, since it is a prerequisite to learning jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is written in javascript.. jQuery is just a library where else javascript is a language itself. Anything that is done jQuery is in javascript.

> jQuery is a fast and concise **JavaScript Library** that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development. jQuery is designed to change the way that you write JavaScript. ~ From jQuery home page

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is JavaScript. It is not another language, but a library that makes some (cross-browser) tasks easier than when using vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: To stealth downvoter: What's wrong with this answer?